# How to prevent grabber apps to download and detect mp3 files from browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, audio-streaming

I am developing a music streaming website (for both premium and free users)

[image: Example]

Like in the screenshot above, if a user has a grabber installed in his browser (apps like IDM and other download accelerator) they can be able to download the files for free yet the website is intended to streaming only.

How can I prevent these kind of apps to detect and download mp3 files from my music streaming website? In case they do download, how can I make sure the files they get unplayable (like what deezer does for eg)?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: 1. Link to audio file cant be in DOM when page loads.2 Do some kind checking if visitor is actual human (lot of different ways to do, I did with verification if user loged-in and hi should click on some dome elements to init AJAX(can be fake player with fake play button)). 3. Return link to file via ajax and init player via JS. 4 and still of some one wants to get that file hi can do that by inspect element and going to network tab. good luck ;)

Comment: Way too broad. You are basically asking us to invent a new DRM system.

Comment: @Robert I wrote it the best way I could, and I aint askin to create somethin for me, I came here for tipsz insights and orientation. And thanks for the word DRM that I didnt know, it sure  will help as I am lookin into that.

Comment: @Beneris thanks a lot for your reply...

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for your reply...

Comment: Added image as embbeded element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t. From the perspective of the server, there is absolutely no difference between downloading and streaming. To protect file from unauthorized playback, you must use DRM.

Comment: Thanks @szatamary for takin time replying my question. I expressed it the best way i could, sorry if it was unclear somehow... Will have a look on the DRM and see how I can implement it... Thanks again